# how to rotate sprite with 180 degree cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        shootVector = ccpSub(location, cannon.position);
        CGFloat shootAngle = ccpToAngle(shootVector);
        cocosAngle = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(-1 * shootAngle);

        CGFloat rotateDiff = cocosAngle;    
        if (rotateDiff > 180)
            rotateDiff -= 360;
        if (rotateDiff < -180)
            rotateDiff += 360;    

        CGFloat rotateSpeed = 360; 
        rotateDuration = fabs(rotateDiff / rotateSpeed);

        [cannon runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                           [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                           [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:nil selector:nil],
                           nil]];

        top.rotation = cannon.rotation;
    }
```

Above code cause rotation on touch moved with 360 degree,instead i want to rotate my cannon in 180 or less degree..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a Maximum and Minmum degres and compare with them if rotateDiff>MaxDegree then set to MAX if rotateDiff<MinDegree then set rotateDiff to MinDegree.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **CCRotateBy** command instead of **CCRotateTo** will cause rotation of a certain amount instead of going to a certain position.  Call it in the same way you would CCRotateTo as below:

```
[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:180]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me either..
It rotates 180 degree even i touch once,i don't want that,instead i want to limit my rotation to 180 degree WHEN FINGER CONTINUE TOUCHES ON CANNON. 
CAN YOU PLEASE CREATE DEMO AND CHECK ONCE ?!